# Far Manager: Highlight file/dirs using external metadata (like SVN, Mercurial, Dropbox, etc)

Tags: git, svn, dropbox, mercurial, far-manager

I've recently migrated to Far Manager 3 and revised my app settings from scratch. One of those improvements was adjusting the file groups highlights (I didn't change them for long time even knowing that they aren't configured nice). They are really great, and I really find them highly customizable and helpful. However, these highlights deal with standard file attributes including names and date/time, totally ignoring any metadata from the outside (for example, Mercurial, Subversion, Dropbox, SkyDrive). Working with revision control systems from command line usually tends to check the status manually, like `svn status` or `hg status`. This is great, but the status info cannot be "replicated" to the panels to visualize the file system. In-panel style can be achieved, for example, in Explorer+TortoiseSVN|Hg|Git with overlay icons, or IntelliJ IDEA (with VCS configuration set up, sure). Ideally, I would like to use the file status highlighting like it was a highlight group: a single character color marker, so it could work in a pure Windows console subsystem (also text mode?). While composing the question, I've googled some related topics:

- [Subversion file statuses in Far Manager (in Russian)](http://cyborginfo.livejournal.com/3246.html) - the post from 2009 describes exactly what I want to achieve (unfortunately, for Subversion only), but in 2011 the author claimed to stop the development due to full migration to Linux. Bad luck.

[image]

- [ConEmu using C0 panel plugins](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/FarManager#There_are_several_types_of_plugins) - not sure what it's really is, SVN 1.6 only (I'm at SVN 8), probably icon overlays from TortoiseSVN, requires ConEmu.

There were also a few links to the Far Manager official forum board, but they weren't encouraging, so I don't believe that my question could be resolved completely, but let me try:

- Is there something like that?
- If not in the direct way: can a tricky composition of plugins help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that. Even with `ConEmu` for `SVN 1.6` it is not possible. Unfortunately.

But you can post it as a wish on [`Far Manager` bugtracker](http://bugs.farmanager.com/).